# Kitaev Chain - Obtaining a real-orthogonal matrix that block-diagonlises the Kitaev Chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, linear-algebra

I encounter a subtle problem regarding the Kitaev Chain. In Kitaev framework, he tried to express the Hamiltonian into real-orthogonal basis. Suppose the Majorana system is described by
$$
H = \frac{i}{4} \sum_{ij} A_{ij} \chi_{i} \chi_{j} , 
$$
where $A$ is a real-skew symmetric matrix. In [Kitaev Honeycomb paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438) (p.15, eq(24)), he said that we can obtain a real-orthgonal matrix $Q$ by first diagonalising the Hermitian matrix $iA$ and obtain the unitary matrix $U$. The odd(even) column of the real-orthogonal matrix $Q$ is then the real(imaginary) part of the eigenvectors of the unitary $U$. The following picture is cropped from Kitave's paper: [image: picture]

$$\\$$

However, I do not understand how Kitaev come up with this method to find a real-orthogonal matrix $Q$. My trial guess is that by first observing the middle matrix sandwiched by $Q$ and $Q^T$ is kind of in $\sigma^{y}$ basis. Following Kitaev suggestion, I consider
$$
iA = U E U^{\dagger} ~,~ E= \text{diag}[\epsilon_{1}, -\epsilon_{1}, \cdots,\epsilon_{n}, -\epsilon_{n}, ] 
$$
The sub-blocks of $E$ matrix are kind of in $\sigma_{Z}$ basis, and my goal is to turn everything into $\sigma_{Y}$ basis
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & - i \epsilon_{i} \\
i\epsilon_{i} & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
V 
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_{i} & 0  \\
0 & -\epsilon_{i} 
\end{pmatrix}
V^{\dagger} , 
$$
with a unitary $V$. I can obtain the middle matrix sandwiched by $Q$ and $Q^{T}$ by the this method. However, now the combination of $U$ and $V$ is still a unitary matrix, not a real-orthogonal matrix nor share similar structure to that $Q$ that provided by Kitaev.  Therefore, I screw up to find such $Q$ under my guess. Could anyone give me some guideline on finding such real-orthogonal matrix $Q$ following similar to Kitaev or point out the incorrect part of my trial method.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got Kitaev construction on the real-orthogonal matrix $Q$ that block-diagonalising the real skew-symmetric matrix $A$. The main idea is to compare these two matrices:
$$
A = Q ~ (\oplus \epsilon_{i} (- \sigma_{y,i} )) ~ Q^{T} ~,~ iA = U ~ (\oplus \epsilon_{i} \sigma_{z,i}) ~ U^{\dagger} . 
$$
By considering the middle matrices(i.e. $\sigma_{y. z}$), we can see that there exists other unitary to relate them
$$
\sigma_{y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}
~\sigma_{z} ~
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}^{\dagger}
$$
However, what we want is $- \sigma_{y}$ instead. Therefore, we can use $\sigma_{x}$ to rotate $sigma_{y}$ such that
$$
\sigma_{y} = \sigma_{x} (- \sigma_{y} )\sigma_{x} . 
$$
We can now combine these ingredients and obtain the following
$$
\sigma_{z} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}^{\dagger} \sigma_{y} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}^{\dagger} \sigma_{x}(-\sigma_{y} ) \sigma_{x}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We then define a matrix $M$ equals to the following matrix products to simplify the notation
$$
M = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}^{\dagger} \sigma_{x} 
= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
-i & 1 \\
i &  1
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \sigma_z = M (-\sigma_y)  M^{\dagger}.
$$
Now we briefly talk about the property of real skew symmetric matrix $A$ and the corresponding unitary $U$. For real skew-symmetric matrix, the eigenvalues of $\epsilon_{i}$ and $- \epsilon_{i}$ is somehow related by following
\begin{equation}
iA | u_{i} \rangle = \epsilon_{i} | u_{i} \rangle, iA |u_{i} \rangle^{*} = (iA |u_{i} \rangle )^{*} = -\epsilon_{i} | u_{i} \rangle^{*}
\end{equation}
Therefore, we can write the corresponding unitary matrix as
$$
U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
|u_{1} \rangle , & |u_{1} \rangle^{*}, &\cdots , &|u_{n} \rangle , &|u_{n} \rangle^{*}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, we restrict our discussion of the first sub-block of $\epsilon_{1}$, the restrict $U_{1}$ is now
$$
U_{1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
|u_{1} \rangle , & |u_{1} \rangle^{*}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore, the matrix product of $U_1 M $ becomes
$$
Q_1 = U_{1} M  = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \text{Im}(|u_{1} \rangle )   , & 2 \text{Re}(|u_{1} \rangle )
\end{pmatrix} ,
$$
which is indeed a real and orthogonal matrix. Now we can apply this method to find out the full real-orthogonal matrix $Q$.